# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() is not working in MS Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: plugins, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm-online, get-request

I have written a plugin wherein I am trying to get an XML response. 
This is my code :

```
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
string strXMLServer = "xxx";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strXMLServer);
request.Method = "POST";

// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "xyz";

// Assuming XML is stored in strXML
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);

// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

//(LINE 5) Get the request stream
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

// Write the data to the request stream. 
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();
```

This code works fine when its written in a console application. But when I copy the same code to a class library(plugin) and tries to debug it using plugin profiler, the application gets stopped abruptly when it reaches (LINE 5)
i.e. At **`Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();`**

request.GetRequestStream() function is not working with plugin, but works fine within a console.

**Any help would be appreciated :)**

**Thanks in advance**

Note: I am using Dynamics 365 online trial version

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to take into consideration when building a plugin with web requests. Firstly, you need to use **WebClient** as it's widely supported by Microsoft products.

Secondly, your URL needs to be a **DNS name** and not an IP address, as this is a hosted plugin in *sandbox* mode.

Example from Microsoft's website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509030.aspx

Reading material: https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/understanding-plugin-sandbox-mode/